# iohub psychopy eyetracking trials identification

Tags: database, psychopy, trial, eye-tracking

I’m sorry for fairly basic question but I can not find an answer in iohub nor psychopy documentation. That is the last thing stopping me starting my first experiment with iohub + PsychoPy with eye tracker.

Is there a way to add a trial identification column (with custom unique names, e.g. stimuli picture) to the iohub events / eyetracking data tables?

I will appreciate a lot any help!

Comment: Hi, the same people will generally be answering PsychoPy questions here and at https://discourse.psychopy.org so you should only ask at one place or the other (and the Discourse site is better suited for to-and-fro how-to discussions rather than here at StackOverflow, which is more oriented to specific programming Q&A).